# How can I connect the ASP.NET Identity database with my own database?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I want to have all the tables in one place, something like the situation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066140/update-database-fires-there-is-already-an-object-named-adresses-in-the-datab) question. Which migrations should I run and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Identity Tables in your application database you can configure your context to inherit from the Identity context. They would be included in the same migration as your other changes.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

See [How can one put application users in the same context as the rest of the objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628144/how-can-one-put-application-users-in-the-same-context-as-the-rest-of-the-objects)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you that create sql script of Asp.net Identity database (database created inside "App_Data" Folder) its contains many tables like AspNetUser, AspNetUserRole etc. . 
And run that script for your database it will create all table which you need for Asp.net identity.

We already done such type of process and it worked fine.